# Share functions between "public" folder and "src" folder - React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing a problem while creating an react pwa application...

Indeed, after setting up my react project with the following command "create-react-app" and adding my proper files I have the following project structure.

```
my-app
  - README.md
  - package.json
  - .gitignore
  - node_modules
  - public
    - favicon.icon
    - index.html
    - manifest.json
    - sw.js
  - src
    - App.css
    - App.js
    - index.css
    - index.js
    - registerServiceWorker.js
    - indexedDB
      - database.js
      - idb.js
    - components
      - home-page
        - HomePage.js
        - homePage.css
      - auth-page
        - AuthPage.js
        - authPage.css
    - services
      - AuthService.js
      - UserService.js
    - global
      - Global.js
```

I registered an service worker from registeredServiceWorker.js named "sw.js". The following file is placed into the public folder.

The problem is: I've develop some functions inside the my "AuthService.js" file which is situate inside the src folder, and I need theses functions into my public "sw.js" file which is situate inside my public folder.

Question is: How can I do that ? I tried several times to import / require AuthService.js file, but react told me 
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ***

Have a look to my sw.js

```
//import * as idb from './src/global/Global.js' // <-- BUG HERE CANNOT IMPORT THE FILE
//import * as idb from './src/services/AuthService.js' // <-- BUG HERE CANNOT IMPORT THE FILE
//import * as idb from './src/indexedDB/database.js'; // <-- BUG HERE CANNOT IMPORT THE FILE


// I would like to get BASE_URL_BACKEND from my src/global/Global.js
// but I can't because I can't import/require anything on sw.js,
// so I hardcoded it...
const BASE_URL_BACKEND = 'http://192.168.1.43:8080';

const cacheName ='emmergency-1.0';

self.addEventListener('install', evt => {
    console.log(`SW installé à ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}`);

    let cachePromise = caches.open(cacheName).then(cache =>{
        return cache.addAll([
            '/'
        ])
        .then(console.log("Cache initialisé"))
        .catch(console.err);
    });

    evt.waitUntil(cachePromise);
});


// Others function here but nothing interesting to understand the problem.
// (... Others functions heres ...)
// Others function here but nothing interesting to understand the problem.



self.addEventListener('sync', event => {
    if(event.tag === 'sync-emergencies'){
        console.log('Attemting to sync', event.tag);

        event.waitUntil(
            getAllEmergency().then(emergencies => {
                const unsynced = emergencies.filter(emergency => emergency.unsynced);

                console.log("UNSYNCED =", unsynced);

                return Promise.all(unsynced.map(emergency => {
                    fetch(`${BASE_URL_BACKEND}/api/calls`, {
                        headers : {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                            // MUST HAVE HERE THE AUTHORIZATION TOKEN 
                            // STORED INSIDE AuthService.js, BUT I CAN'T
                            // BECAUSE OF THE IMPOSSIBILITY TO IMPORT / REQUIRE FILES
                        },
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: JSON.stringify(emergency)
                    })
                    .then(() => {

                        // I need "putEmergency" function which is coded inside database.js, but I can't due to the impossibility to import / require external file...
                        //return putEmergency(Object.assign({}, emergency, { unsynced: false}), emergency.id);
                    })
                    .catch( (error) => {
                      console.log('Erreur lors du push :', error)
                    });
                }))
            })
        )
    }
});
```

Could someone help and suggest and answser please. I'm stuck here for 3 days now... Thank you.

Comment: Yes, post it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add an entry for building your serviceworker in your webpack config if you want to use import like this.

If your files were plain js available after build, you could have used [importScripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts)

Edit to recap the comment section :

`create-react-app` use webpack, but it's hidden. To have access to the webpack config files, you've to run `npm run eject`.

Once you've done that, you'll have to modify webpacks config files to add an entry to your service worker like below.

```
entry: { sw: paths.appServiceWorker, main: [require.resolve('./polyfills'), paths.appIndexJs] }
```

This will generate a new file in the static/js folder once you build the project. This is what you want to register as a service worker.

Comment: Have you got an example of a webpack config file ? I never did that before... Thank you

Comment: I haven't implement any webpack config on my react project at this time.

Comment: Ok, i've found the "create-react-app" command, and indeed there's no build process. Well, es6 module import are not support yet in service worker. Unless you change your whole project to use webpack, you're kinda screwed

Comment: So should I have another solution without using es6 but plain js ?

Comment: After a little of digging, it appear that there is a webpack under the hood. You can make it appearby running npm run eject (this is permanent). But once you're there, you can add an entry to your webpack config
 ` entry: { sw: paths.appServiceWorker, main: [require.resolve('./polyfills'), paths.appIndexJs] },` for instance. This while generate a sw.js file in the static folder that you can use as a service worker

Comment: Thank you, problem solved ! Need to go forward, so I duplicate the code from src to public for the moment, later I'll try to clean that...